# Redirect to a different domain and keep URL (while removing a segment) with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Okay I have been wracking my brain trying to figure this one out.

Here is what I am trying to do:

> http://example.com/stuff/uploads/foo/image.png

--- redirect to --->

> http://images.example.com/foo/image.png

My current htaccess manages to match a part of the rule and redirect. It doesn't insert the proper part of the path into the new rewrite though, and that's the main hurdle I am facing.

```
# .htaccess in /stuff/uploads/ directory

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 ^(foo)
RewriteRule ^(foo)(.*)$ http://images.example.com$2 [L,R=301]
```

So in essence I am trying to:

1. Match specific directories in the uploads directory.
2. Redirect to a new domain while preserving part of the original path, but not all.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I just changed the last line to:

> RewriteRule ^(foo)(.*)$ http://images.example.com/$1$2 [L,R=301]

The `$1$2` at the end adds the URL segment that I want and the file name.

Cheers SO!